# Hilbert's axioms - axioms of ordering. A model that does not satisfy the fourth ordering axiom.

Tags: geometry, axioms

Indicate the model that meets the conditions II.1, II.2, II.3 and not II.4. In this case, you need to indicate a set of points and a ternary relation in this set.

Ordering axioms:

II1. If B lies between A, C, then A, B, C are different and lie on one straight line.

II2. If A, B, C are different points on a straight line and B is between A, C, then B is between C, A.

II3. If A and C are two points on a straight line, then there is at least one point B lying between A and
C and at least one point D lying such that C lies between A and D.

II4. Of any three different points on the straight line, there is always one and only one which lies between the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the standard Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with relation:

$$B \text{ lies between } A \text{ and } C :\iff \left(A\neq C \text{ and } B \text{ is the midpoint of segment } AC\right)$$

Btw, it's not a question about Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Why in this case the axiom number 4 is not fulfilled? In this case, after all, only point B lies between A and C.

Comment: You can easily find 3 points on one line such that none of them is the midpoint of the remaining two.

Comment: But we only have three points defined, A, B, and C. Can we find others even though we haven't defined them?

Comment: After all, B lies between A and C, and this is the only point between the other two

Comment: I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: We have to find an example of a mathematical model so that this model does not satisfy the II4 axiom. In this model you gave this model will fulfill the II4 axiom, because the only point between the other two is point B. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Axiom II4 states two things: existence and uniqueness. In my model the existence part will not be fulfilled, hence axioms II4 fails.

Comment: Why? 
Could you draw it? Please

Comment: There is no need to draw. Look at the axiom II4. It says that for any 3 distinct collinear points one of them lies between the other two (existence part) and at most one of them lies between the other two (uniqueness part).